# Ubuntu how to give read permission only for owner

Tags: ubuntu, permissions

i need to give read permission to only the owner of the directory and sub directory.no other user can read the files in the directory.how to do this in command line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`chmod -R 700 directory_name` recursively sets all the permissions for yourself, leaving none for the others.

Comment: This will set permissions for files in that directories as well. I'm not sure that this is desired

Comment: Probably, the OP did not specify this. If that's the case I will delete.

Comment: We will see. After reading the question again twice, I'm not sure anymore ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `find` command for this:

```
find -type d -exec chmod 0500 {} \;
```

Note that read permissions only will not work for a directory to list it's contents. Additionally the executable permission must be given. Therefore 0500

Comment: a more advanced use case can only set permissions on directories or files or a pattern of either or both

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
chmod -R 700 yourDir
```